# How to access a ContentItemfield text field in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

This sounds like a (very) silly question but I just can't find a way to access a text field I've just added to a content type in Orchard. I know how to access the field when it is added to a content part, but not when it is added directly to the content type itself.

The content type is called Product, it is containable and is being shown in a list. I've added the ordinary parts, plus two custom fields: a MediaPicker field named "Image" and a Text field with HTML flavor named "About". The code I'm using to render the list which contains it is the following:

```
@using Orchard.DisplayManagement.Shapes;
@{
    var list = Model.List;
    var items = list.Items;
    var count = items.Count;
    var listTag = Tag(list, "ul");
    listTag.AddCssClass("historia");
    var index = 0;
}

<div class="produtos">
    @foreach (var item in items)
    {
        var itemTag = Tag(item, "div");
        itemTag.AddCssClass("item-" + index);
        @itemTag.StartElement;
        <h3>@item.ContentItem.TitlePart.Title</h3>
        <img src="@Href(item.Image.Url)" 
            class="@item.Image.Class"
            alt="@item.Image.AlternateText" 
            width="@item.Image.Width" 
            height="@item.Image.Height" 
            style="@item.Image.Style" />
        <p>@item.About.Text</p>
        @itemTag.EndElement;
        ++index;
    }
</div>
@Display(Model.List)
@Display(Model.Pager)
```

The problem is that @item.Image does not yeilds the Image field, nor does @item.About yields the "About" text field. I don't even know if a Text field has a .Text property to access its value, after all it can have HTML flavor... I don't even know where to look in the source code to help me finding out how this is done!

I've tried some different approaches like @item.ContentFields.About.Text or @item.ContentField.About.Text, @item.Fields[0], @item.ContentItem.About.Text, @item.ContentItem.ContentFields.About.Text (the last two throws an exception telling me that ContentItem doesn't have those fields...)

I know that if I had added the fields to a content part and this part to the content type I could have done this: @item.ContentItem.TheNameOfTheContentPart.Image.Url ...

I'm becoming more and more frustrated as I can't figure out how to do the simplest things in Orchard. I need that Eureka moment that will make me able to know where to look at in the source code to find answers to these kind of questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A field is *always* under a part. It's just that if you add the field from the admin, a part with the same name as the type will be created automatically for you.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/396280

You can't add a field to a content type, you always add it to a content part. It's just that if that part has the same name as the type, nice magical things happen.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/discussions/397426

Comment: I cant access to field with this way!
Considering that i created the 'News' contenttype in admin, I tried to access Model.ContentItem.NewsPart.Fields.First(f => f.Name == "Picture"), but it trows exception. what is the problem?

Comment: Your picture field is not on the NewsPart part. Also, there is no good reason to use that complicated syntax. `Model.ContentItem.NewsPart.Picture` would be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try your luck replacing values, it will kill your time and you end up with little to no real result. The recommended way is to use Shape Tracing to do this. Search on the Internet for Orchard Shape Tracing and you are good to go. :)

Comment: I've been using shape tracing but it doesn't help in this case. I've figure it out, in fact I've found Bertrand's answer to a similar question on Orchard's forum: "A field is *always* under a part. It's just that if you add the field from the admin, a part with the same name as the type will be created automatically for you." (http://orchardprofile.codeplex.com/discussions/257951)

So, in my case I would have to use: @item.ContentItem.Product.Image.Url for example...

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy it is "more or less" resolved... I can access the field, but since it has HTML "flavor" I can't output it as HTML (the final text includes the markup as if it was escaped and it shows in the plain text). I should post it as another question... and post the solution to this one here...

Comment: Html.Raw is your friend when it's not stabbing you in the back, but in this instance it should be relatively friendly.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy don't you want to answer this one here with a link to your original answer at Orchard forums? After all THIS IS YOUR ANSWER? This way I can at least "say" thank you by accepting your answer... :-) -> "A field is always under a part. It's just that if you add the field from the admin, a part with the same name as the type will be created automatically for you." (orchardprofile.codeplex.com/discussions/257951)

Comment: OK then... Doing this now. By the way, your link above is not pointing to the right thread.